# Getting error, foreach not applicable to type 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot'

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have added game rules in Firebase Firestore in Array format. I want to show all the strings of the array in new lines. But when I'm trying to pull the value from firebase, I'm getting this error, "foreach not applicable to type 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot'".
Here's the code,

**Activity**

```
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("categories").document(categoryId).collection("rules").document("rule").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            String data = "";
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : documentSnapshot) {
                Rules model = doc.toObject(Rules.class);
                App.logMessage("Item Added" + model.oneRule);

                for (String rule : model.getTheRules()) {
                    data += "\n*" + rule;
                }
                //rules.add(model);
                rule.setText(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Model**

```
public class Rules {

List<String> theRules;

public Rules(List<String> theRules) {
    this.theRules = theRules;
}

public List<String> getTheRules() {
    return theRules;
}

public void setTheRules(List<String> theRules) {
    this.theRules = theRules;
}

public Rules(){}
```

}

Firestore screenshot
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire error message that you get.

Comment: @AlexMamo
Edited properly. Kindly check

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo for(QuerDocumentSnapshot doc : documentSnapshot). This line is showing error and the underlined line is documentSnapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the following reference:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("categories")
    .document(categoryId).collection("rules").document("rule")
```

It means that you are trying to read the content of a single document called "rule". When you are calling `get()` and attach a success listener, the argument that comes from the `onSuccess()` method is of type [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot), which isn't an iterable object. So there is no way you iterate on such an object, hence that error. If you want to map the "rule" document into an object of type "Rules", then remove the for loop and simply use:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("categories").document(categoryId).collection("rules").document("rule").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        String data = "";
        Rules model = doc.toObject(Rules.class);
        for (String rule : model.getTheRules()) {
            data += "\n*" + rule;
        }
        rule.setText(data);
    }
});
```

The result of the above lines of code will be the concatenation of all rules inside the `matchRule` array which will be added to the rule TextView.

The solution above will work **only** if you change the name of the array in the database `matchRule` to match the name of the list `theRules` in your `Rules` class. Or you add the following annotation in front of the getter like this:

```
@PropertyName("matchRule")
public List<String> getTheRules() {
    return theRules;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
public class Rules {

    public Rules(){}

    List<String> matchRule;

    public Rules(List<String> matchRule) {
        this.matchRule = matchRule;
    }

    public List<String> getMatchRule() {
        return matchRule;
    }

    public void setMatchRule(List<String> matchRule) {
        this.matchRule = matchRule;
    }
}
```

Comment: After applying the, I'm getting this following error.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.luteraa.luteraaesports, PID: 5202
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.luteraa.luteraaesports.Rules.getMatchRule()' on a null object reference
        at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.TournamentDetailsActivity$1.onSuccess(TournamentDetailsActivity.java:135)
        at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.TournamentDetailsActivity$1.onSuccess(TournamentDetailsActivity.java:128)

Comment: at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8043)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)

Comment: kindly help me with this

Comment: Pelase change this `List<String> theRules;` into this `List<String> theRules; = new ArrayList<>();` in your `Rules`.

Comment: Or change the code as in my updated answer and use `for (String rule : model.getMatchRule())`. is ok now?